# Python, change interpreter what use system. From anaconda2/bin/python2.7 to /usr/bin/pyhon2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, interpreter, conda

Hello, stackoverflow I need help again :)

How to change default system python interpreter?
**OR**
How to solve this? -->

[image]

Problem comes after installation of anaconda2. It's not "just gnome-tweak-tool" problem of course :).

It's obviously that system - somehow - run anaconda-python interpreter, instead /usr/bin/python as a default system python interpreter.

Which python status-->

[image]

I cannot delete Anaconda from my Opensuse Leap 42.1 system... I need just disable him for a while..

THX

Comment: edit your `.bashrc` file to set PYTHONPATH.

Comment: .bashrc file:  https://ghostbin.com/paste/86gkw

Comment: comment those paths added by anaconda and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much.You solve the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your `.bashrc` file to add PYTHONPATH or comment the paths added by anaconda  then it will work.