# How to set the default python interpreter to Anaconda2 path, rather than usr/bin/ default in WSL

Tags: bash, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to change the PATH variable from the default in WSL (/user/bin) to the Anaconda2 path in in C drive in windows.

This is similar to this question: [Python, change interpreter what use system. From anaconda2/bin/python2.7 to /usr/bin/pyhon2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38284874/python-change-interpreter-what-use-system-from-anaconda2-bin-python2-7-to-usr) , but I think that user has his Anaconda installed after his WSL installation, in WSL. I'm trying to redirect my python interpreter in bash from the WSL usr/bin to the Anaconda I installed in my windows drive here:

```
c/Users/631/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda21
```

Here's how I've tried to modify my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH=../../mnt/c/Users/631/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/:../../mnt/c/Users/631/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/Scripts/:../../mnt/c/Users/631/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/Library/bin:$PATH
```

But so far bash has ignored my python interpreter in Anaconda.

Comment: Can WSL run Windows executables? Can you run, e.g., notepad.exe?

Comment: @darthbith I just tried notepad.exe and it works. So it seems to.

Comment: Did you restart the terminal after updating your bashrc?

Comment: @darthbith, yes I did that too.

Comment: Why do you use relative ´../../mnt/c/…´ instead of absolute ´/mnt/c/…´? (Here is `…` _Horizontal Ellipsis_ used to indicate an intentional omission of the ends.) And which name is right? `Anaconda21` or `Anaconda2`?